# How to check MPVolumeView's route button is visible

Tags: ipad, mpvolumeview

Is there any methods which can check the MPVolumeView's route button is visible on iPad?

Now i can access the route button through the below code, but i have no idea why i check the button's hidden, alpha are always 0 whether it's visible or not.

```
for (UIButton *button in volumeView.subviews) {
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        // here the button is route button
    }
}
```

Any help are appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real official way to check if airplay is available.

There is however a project on github called airplayDetector that uses the approach you are trying, by checking the alpha value of the button by "watching" the property.

This is taken from  *AirPlayDetector/AirPlayDetector.m*

```
for (UIView *view in volumeButton.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        airplayButton = [view retain];
        [airplayButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"alpha" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
}
```

You can find the relevant code here : https://github.com/StevePotter/AirPlayDetector

The original code is not ARC compliant but the forks are, so check those if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 7.0 there is a property called `areWirelessRoutesAvailable`. You can also register for the notification `MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification`.